# Google App Engine request being executed multiple times

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an issue with our Python 2.7 Google App Engine project where after a lot of research it appears as though App Engine is repeatedly sending through the same request to our servers. Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

EDIT:

It's a standard request with all the same parameters as it was first sent with (some of which are 15 days old now). I'm wandering if it's a similar situation to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/9fAYP7UyppQ

Comment: Is it your app that keeps sending the request to your servers? Is some other app sending the request to your servers? What request? Is it a CRON? A TASK? Could you provider more details?

Answer (score 1):

Typically App Engine doesn't send requests, it's the framework you use to *handle* requests.

If you're getting duplicate requests coming in, you should look to see where it's coming from. If it's coming from an app engine server to your own external server, then somebody is running some sort of process on *their* app engine account that's accessing data from your server during its execution.

The details, including what you would do about it, are all situation-dependent. There's no catch-all response. Just be aware that, yes, any computer on the Internet can make web requests to any other. And that includes app engine (in both directions).

Comment: Thanks Tyler. It's happened before when one of their front end load balances was erroneously sending requests repeatedly. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/9fAYP7UyppQ I'm trying to work out if it's specfic to our app this time or a general problem.

Comment: You can determine this by checking to see where the requests originate from. Could you do this and report back what it is? It may be a cron task or task queue in another module/instance of your app, or it may be coming from a user machine... we won't know without more log info. Given that the error about multiple requests occurred last year based on an infrastructure level, it seems unlikely that it is still the same bug in the link you provided.